# I don't have Startup.cs and appsettings.jason files in my solution explorer , how can I implement database connection into my project

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

While creating an ASP.NET MVC project with AngularJS, the `appsettings.json` and `startup.cs` files are missing. Is there any way to create them or any another options to get connection from database..?

Comment: Those files are part of any ASP.NET **Core** application - not of a solution targeting the standard, classic, full .NET framework (used for ASP.NET MVC) ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appsettings.json` and `Startup.cs` are for ASP.NET Core applications, your ASP.NET MVC must be targetting ASP.NET Framamework, so to connect to the database recides in Web.config.

It should be added to `<connectionStrings>` section after `<configSections>` section in `<configuration>` block.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultContext" connectionString="data source=ServerName;initial catalog=DatabaseName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

You can read more at [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string)